# Is it better to constantly write to a file, or keep data in memory and write at the end?

Tags: performance, io

I'm writing a test suite for timing my algorithms against publicly available code. Each test run takes less than a second, ranging from very fast for small problem sizes, to ~900 ms for larger problems.

I expect to write one line per test, no more than 200 characters per line. I need to print the time taken by each of the two algorithms, the error between them, and the seed used to generate the problem. I expect to run 2000 tests in a single run, but this number should also be flexible. If necessary, I could break up them into smaller runs.

I expect to run several thousand tests in a single session, which may take several hours. Therefore, it is critical to ensure the data is not lost should anything happen half-way through a batch of tests. But constantly writing to a file might be too slow.

I am trying to decide if I should write to the log file after every test, or store the results in memory and only print them after a batch of, say, 10 tests, or at the end of all the tests.  How much of a difference (in speed) would these different approaches make on average?

Comment: “might” be too slow – did you try it? The easy way to handle this is by writing to a buffer and writing the buffer to a file, which is how stdio works already.

Comment: @Ryan As long as they don't manually call fflush, anyway.

Comment: Also, is this C++ or C?

Comment: DeoxNa, how many bytes are you printing per test? How many tests are there?  It's hard to judge this without some more concrete numbers, although the answer's probably going to be "just let stdio handle the buffering", as Ryan said.

Comment: Also depends on the data.  If the program crashes in the middle, the data won't be written.  Is it better if there is some data before a crash?

Comment: @Ryan Technically it's CUDA C++ and I'm using nvcc for compilation, so either one can be used, though C++ may be easier to use.

Comment: What do you mean with "technically"? If it is CUDA, the C tag is definitively missplaced here. CUDA is not related to C, but a C++ **variant**. And your problem becomes different with that. (not that it not is still too broad).

Comment: @Ray I expect to write one line per test, no more than 200 characters per line. I need to print the time taken by each of the two algorithms, the error between them, and the seed used to generate the problem. I expect to run 2000 tests in a single run, but this number should also be flexible. If necessary, I could break up them into smaller runs.

Comment: @Olaf Fair point. Since all the file I/O is done on the host, I figured it wasn't necessary to add the cuda tag.

Comment: Honestly, that's a tiny enough file that it really doesn't matter.  I'd say flush the output after each test since you're worried about it crashing partway through.  But even if you flushed the output after every *character*, this would finish in a matter of seconds.  stdio (or iostream if you're feeling particularly verbose) will buffer automatically, so you can print as often as you want; just call `fflush(file)` or `file << std::flush` to force it to flush the buffer after each test.

Comment: @Olaf, this is hardly CUDA specific.  It's barely even C++ specific.  Is there  an `I/O` tag or something like that?

Comment: @ray: That's why I think it is too broad, not just POB (as which it will be closed most likely). I agree the language -tag does not make it on-topic, I edited it mostly to get it of the search for the unrelated tags until it goes down the drain.

Comment: @Olaf I'm not sure it's *that* broad or opinion based.  The amount of time spent writing to the log is less than a second and the amount of total runtime is several hours.  So "print the output as often as you want", while *technically* an opinion, is clearly the *correct* opinion in this case.  A good answer would expand on that a bit so as to cover *why* it's the right approach so as to be more useful to people with similar problems and different numbers, but writing such an answer is quite practical.

Comment: @Ray: I don't give a [...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbYWhdLO43Q) about this anymore. I'm done trying to keep this site's quality high. Do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expect to run several thousand tests in a single session, which may take several hours. **Therefore, it is critical to ensure the data is not lost should anything happen half-way through a batch of tests.** But constantly writing to a file might be too slow.

I think you got your answer right there. Writing to file is not that slow actually (if you're only writing a small line or two to report the result of your test).

**Edit**: I just saw your comment, you only want to write 200 chars, then don't bother with the following. Write it directly.

<s>If you have a huge amount of text to write, you might want to create another thread handling all the writing while you perform your test. I would however, advise against this because it might slow down your test and screw up you results if your tests are already multithreaded or are using I/O too. (It might also introduce a lot of problems if you're not familiar with threading and communication between threads).</s>

From reading your post I might also suspect that you're interested in the timing of each test. If this is the case, you might just want to pause the timer, write to your file, and then resume it between each test.